# Typescript interface on destructed object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a typescript error with my object that i'm destructing in React / ts.

When I destructure `notificationData` in the publish function I get this error

Property 'messages' does not exist on type 'Notifications | undefined'.ts(2339)

I'm not sure why?

Comment: `notificationData?` marks the property as optional. Hence it might *not* be there. So, you either need to handle the case where `notificationData` doesn't exist (by providing a fallback or checking beforehand) or make it non-optional (assuming that it's indeed always going to be there, as your code expects here).

Answer (score 0):

@VLAZ is correct. Since messages is marked with `?`, you have to handle the case where it might be `undefined`. I suggest you pass a default value same as you did with `domain`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `notificationData` maybe `undefined`. So you should add conditions before using it

```
  const {
    url = '',
    notificationData,
  } = props;

  const messages = notificationData?.messages;
  const totalunread = notificationData?.totalunread ;
```